# I have two heads?

Tags: riddle

I have two heads

They never come near

I've many friends, whose death is clear

The lucky ones can live again and again

When I die I'm replaced by a twin.

What am I?

Hint:

> I'm used nearly every day, but often ignored

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am a

> Battery

I have two heads
They never come near

> Two ends of a battery

I've many friends, whose death is clear

> There are many, many dead batteries around

The lucky ones can live again and again

> Rechargable batteries

When I die I'm replaced by a twin.

> If one battery dies, you buy a new one (same type) and replace it.

Comment: Man, I thought I made it a bit cocealed, what gave it away?

Comment: @Jason_ - not sure why I came up with the answer, just started thinking of everyday things, but (I think) the `lucky ones can live again and again` may have been the line that made me think of the answer.

Comment: Well great guess!

Answer (score 5):

> A Pencil

I have two heads

They never come near

> Point and Eraser at opposing ends

I've many friends, whose death is clear

> Broken, dull, or sharpened to an unusable length

The lucky ones can live again and again

> Can be sharpened again and again. Alternatively, mechanical pencils should be essentially infinitely reusable

When I die I'm replaced by a twin.

> Pencils are essentially identical, and you'll likely replace one with another.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, and great answer! c:

Comment: The two "heads" of the pencil can actually come near by sharpening too much.

Answer (score 2):

> I think the answer is batteries.

I have two heads

> The poles of the battery, used to power the device the get plugged into.

They never come near

> The battery is a fixed shape and so the two heads of a single battery do not touch.

I've many friends whose death is clear

> Batteries are said to "die."  And you can tell they have died when the device you are using loses power.  Also, some batteries let you gauge the power left in them by holding down certain points.

The lucky ones can live again and again

> Rechargeable batteries escape the fate of their normal brethren.

When I die I'm replaced by a twin.

> Normally you don't mix battery types, so you replace like for like.  Also people normally buy a single type at a time.

Hint:

> I am used nearly every day but often ignored.
>  You don't give batteries a thought until your device stops working.  So you often ignore them.

Edit:  Too slow on mobile, someone beat me to it.

Comment: Your reasoning was great though!

Comment: Thanks.  I like your puzzles by the way.  It's not some obscure computer coding language mystery or something.

Comment: Thanks I enjoy coming up with riddles, I'll post another one tomorrow if I can